# Reshaping panel data to dataframe pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am sorry if it is already answered. I have tried to search for answer, but couldn't find one. I have a panel dataframe which I got after some manipulations. The orignal data was something like :

```
 Date        op   count
 2014-10-21  AE     23
 2014-10-22  BA     55
 .....................
```

After using panel and combining with another dataframe it now looks like

```
Index       AE  BA  ZA  FG ....
2014-10-21  11  22  34  11 ....
```

How can I change it back to orignal format ? Thank you in advance for any information or help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> df.set_index('Index').stack().reset_index()
        Index level_1   0
0  2014-10-21      AE  11
1  2014-10-21      BA  22
2  2014-10-21      ZA  34
3  2014-10-21      FG  11
```